# Edit form that has ForeignKey to other model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a form that a user need to fill up, the model of that form as ForeignKey to another model (Question)

When I create a new form, it works as I expect.
When I try to do edit an existing record I am able to get the relevant data in the template but when I click on submit It fails with no error – when I debug it its failes on form is not valid and that the question is None.

```
# form
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=_(u'question'),
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        queryset=Question.objects.all())
    description = forms.CharField(
        label=_(u'description'),
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '4'}),
    max_length=2000,
    required = False)
link = forms.URLField(
    label=_(u'link'),
    max_length=1000,
    required = False)
price = forms.DecimalField(
    label=_(u'price'),
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    #max_length=100,
    required = False)
currency = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label=_(u'currency'),
    required=False,
    queryset=Currency_converter.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Answer
    exclude = ('user','link_domain_name',)
    fields = ['link','price', 'currency','description']

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(AnswerForm, self).clean()
    if cleaned_data.get('link')==''  and cleaned_data.get('price')==None and 
cleaned_data.get('description')=='' :
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("You must fill at least one field!"))
    if cleaned_data.get('link')=='' and cleaned_data.get('price')!=None :
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Add link to the price you found!"))
    if cleaned_data.get('price')!=None and 
cleaned_data.get('currency')==None :
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("set currency for the price you 
set!"))
    return cleaned_data 

        #view
    def answer(request,question_id ,answer_id):
        path_to_pic = filepath_link_as_pictures()
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        if answer_id != '0':
            instance = get_object_or_404(Answer, pk=answer_id)
            if instance.user != request.user:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            instance = Answer()
            instance.question = question
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        if request.POST :
           if form.is_valid():
               ....
#HTML
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
 <div class="form-group">
{{ field.label_tag }}

{% if form.is_bound %}
  {% if field.errors %}
    {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ error }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
{% endif %}

{% if field.help_text %}
  <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
{% endif %}
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It looks like I miss something as I get all the data in the template why don’t I get the question field as hidden filed in the template as well?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have defined question as a choice field and as hidden input in your model form? Those are not compatible.

Comment: I set it to hiddden the user doesnt need to see that field , and its ForeignKey  thats why I set it to choice field, I see what you say but is that the couse of the problem? and how sould I do that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem but I guess it's around that. When you create an object is question a hidden input or a choice field? How is the value set?

Comment: @guillermo Its done in  instance.question = question, I remove the hidden for debug and I see that in new I get the quesiton and in edit I dont get it, its None

Comment: question is ModelChoiceField when I added initial = { 'question':question})  I have the question but instead of update the exsiting record it create a new record?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
ModelChoiceField need to be  initial

```
initial = { 'question':question})
```

secound thing you need to pass the answer.id as well and it was removed by mistake, so it created a new record instead of update existing one

```
{% url 'answer' question.id  form.instance.id|default_if_none:0 %}
```